# How do I prompt a modal when the user leaves my website in Javascript/AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, dom-events, onbeforeunload

Is there a way in AngularJS or Javascript to detect that the user is leaving my website (can be closing his browser or entering another page) and to prompt a modal?
In this modal I want to ask the user why he is leaving.

Also, is it OK to have something like this? Will my website be blacklisted due to this "annoying: feature?

Comment: Annoying? yes. The only time it's more or less accepted is when the user has entered data, and thus avoid an accidental exit with loss of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To combat unwanted pop-ups, modern browsers severely limit what JavaScript can do before a page unloads.

From the Docs:

> ## Window: beforeunload event
>
> The `beforeunload` event is fired when the window, the document and its resources are about to be unloaded. The document is still visible and the event is still cancelable at this point.
>
> This event enables a web page to trigger a confirmation dialog asking the user if they really want to leave the page. If the user confirms, the browser navigates to the new page, otherwise it cancels the navigation.

For more information, see

- [MDN Web API Reference - Window: `beforeunload` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event)

Answer (score 0):

With Angular use

```
$scope.$on("$locationChangeStart",function(){
     //do your stuff here
});
```

to detect when the user leaves the page.

If you use `alert('your message');`, the browser will problably give the user an option to block alerts from your site.

Comment: Perhaps opening a small window would be not so harmful?

Comment: Most users will not like having a new window opening every time they close the site.

Comment: If it only opens every 10th time, it should be already better perhaps?

Comment: Take a look at this question at UX Stack Exchange: [link](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/45550/preventing-users-from-closing-browser-tab-bad-idea)